# How to make the GETDATE dynamic so that if reports run on any date it should show the information of the specified date

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a SQL query to make the GETDATE dynamic so that if reports run on any date it should  show the information of the specified date.

```
CASE WHEN PERIOD_TYPE='DAY' THEN 

(SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET) as SALES_BUDGET_DAY FROM 
(
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.SGFOM_TX_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY='2020-11-29'--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.MYFOM_TX_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY='2020-11-29'--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.ID_TX_SAPBI_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY='2020-11-29'--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
--JOIN  SITE AND GROUP BY CATGEORYY ETC
) A )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as a variable:

```
DECLARE @date DATE=DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));

CASE WHEN PERIOD_TYPE='DAY' THEN 

(SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET) as SALES_BUDGET_DAY FROM 
(
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.SGFOM_TX_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY=@date--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.MYFOM_TX_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY=@date--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(SALES_BUDGET)  AS SALES_BUDGET
FROM ANALYSE.ID_TX_SAPBI_BUDGET
WHERE CALENDAR_DAY=@date--CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
--JOIN  SITE AND GROUP BY CATGEORYY ETC
) A )
```

Comment: Also: I'd **strongly recommend** not using `GETDATE()-1` - that's not entirely clear. Instead - use the `DATEADD` function: `DATEADD(DAY; -1, GETDATE())` is much clearer - you want to subtract **1 day** from the current date.

Comment: @marc_s +1 and it also fails completely with `SYSDATETIME()`